# Inclue CSS file

Tags: html, css

I included css file as follows, but does not work.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_control/navi.css" />
    <div class="navi"> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">introduce</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">event</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">gallery<a></li>
            <li><a href="#">board<a></li>
            <li><a href="#">road</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">music</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

What am I wrong?

Comment: What's the error ? See HTTP server log a,d/or browser.

Comment: could you more clear?  how are you including it?  it looks like you just provided a snippet of HTML?  What is the context?  is thIS the HTML output?  Please provide all relevant code and actually explain your issue and what you've tried.  This is too vauge.  Also, are your paths correct?

Comment: Please define "does not worked". What did you expect and what is it doing instead?

Comment: do you have a folder named _control with a css file named navi.css in the root?

Comment: Yes, "navi.css" file loacte at http://myserver.com/_contron/navi.css.

Comment: Drewdin/ "navi.css" file is located at root/_control folder.

Comment: Where is the CSS file relative to the HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide more information in your question, but see what this does. Your CSS link is fine. A few things you should check:

- The path to your CSS file. If necessary for ease of understanding, be explicit
- Make sure the  tag is within the  tag, and the  is within the  tag.
- Make sure your CSS file accurately references the HTML tags you're trying to style. This may look like:

  .navi li a, #navi li a:link{
    /* regular style */
  }
  .navi li a:hover{
    /*on hover*/
  }

Answer (score 0):

You should to put `<link>`s in the `<head></head>` section of your page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_control/navi.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

If that does not work, make sure the file path is correct.

Comment: Added "<head>", but still does not work.

Comment: @WindStory Then you would have entered **wrong path** . Have you placed your html file in correct directory?

Comment: @venkat/ The path is correct, I checked and checked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the leading slash? Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_control/navi.css" />
```

Comment: user985219/ Yes, but does not work.

Comment: It really does seem to be path related then. Have you tried it with a full URL? Like: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.com/_control/navi.css" />

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://myserver.dtdns.net:8080/_control/temple_navi.css" /> - But I can see |view source" at browser.

Comment: You can see the CSS source? Is your HTML file located at myserver.dtdns.net:8080 or is it in myserver.dydns.net:8080/_control?